# Getting Visual Studio to build pseudo-language (qps-ploc) satellite assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, localization, resources, resx, pseudolocalization

I've generated pseudo-localized versions of an app's resource files (for example `Order Summary and Payment` is localized as `[[[[[Òŕd̂ër̊ S̀úm̂m̈år̀ý ân̈d̊ P̀áŷm̈e̊ǹt́]]]]]`) so that we can test for localizability bugs ahead of getting actual translations.

I have named them using the qps-ploc resource identifier to match the existing [pseudo-locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) identifier, e.g. my pseudo-localized version of `Details.resx` is named `Details.qps-ploc.resx`.

However when I add these resx files to the project, Visual Studio ignores them. If I rename them using a "real" language code (such as `Details.fr-FR.resx`) then Visual Studio does create a subfolder named with this language code and builds the satellite assembly.

So it looks to me like Visual Studio rejects qps-ploc (without even a build warning). Am I missing something or can anyone suggest a way to get these qps-ploc resources built as part of my Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The qps- locales work fine in my ASP.NET web application with .resx files (not compiled resource dll), however, I did find this MS article on enabling pseudo locales in the registry. Perhaps it will help.

[Using Pseudo-Locales for Localization Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Additionally, you may wish to create custom locales, as given in this MS article:

[How to: Create Custom Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx)

Best regards.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I added those registry entries from http://tinyurl.com/7ls3o7q (and rebooted) and now Visual Studio does recognize my qps-ploc resx files and builds satellite assemblies for them. So it appears that Visual Studio queries the system for a list of valid locale IDs, and that until those registry keys are added, the pseudo locales aren't enumerated by the system.

Comment: One more caveat: as per [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982%28v=prot.10%29.aspx), qps-ploc is only truly supported from Server 2008 R2. In my place our build server runs an older version, and fails to build qps-ploc, so we had to pick a different locale name (one from the supported list that we knew we won't be using--not nice but no other option)

Comment: And one more caveat: per [this Microsoft Doc] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/using-pseudo-locales-for-localization-testing), the behaviour changed in Windows 1803 such that qps- locales will *never* appear in an enumerated list of locales - regardless of the magical registry entries that used to work. I am currently finding that Visual Studio (15.8.4) won't build qps-ploc resources, and I suspect this change is the cause. I've reported a problem about it from inside Visual Studio.